# How to tell what the kernel is from uname -a command?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

I have an ec2 instance of which I cannot tell the exact operating system.

I typed in `uname -a` and it shows:

```
2.6.18-274.7.1.el5xen #1 SMP Thu Oct 20 17:06:34 EDT 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

It's not indicating whether it's ubuntu, centOS, debian, or others. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Those are distributions, the operating system is `GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lsb_release is one command to look into. Here's the manpage: http://linux.die.net/man/1/lsb_release

Sample usage:

```
ben@ubuntu:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 11.10
Release:    11.10
Codename:   oneiric
```

Or you can specify just the distributor id:

```
ben@ubuntu:~$ lsb_release -i
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
```